# Only the last element of the list displayed in Knockout

Tags: knockout.js

I have a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aDahT/3025/) where I am trying to generate a list with foreach

```
<ul data-bind="foreach: allItems">
<li ><p data-bind="text: name"></p></li>
</ul>
```

but only the last element of the array is displayed. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your fiddle is only declaring a single array item.

```
this.allItems = ko.observableArray([{name:"Fries", name:"Eggs Benedict", name:"Ham", name:"Cheese"}]);
```

Should be

```
this.allItems = ko.observableArray([{name:"Fries"}, {name:"Eggs Benedict"}, {name:"Ham"}, {name:"Cheese"}]);
```